# angularjs $http.post to MVC Controller with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angularjs-http

The $http.post method from angular to MVC controller with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] throws a 500 internal server error with the below message. [We are calling the controller passing the __RequestVerificationToken in header as well as the data.]
We are using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc-6.0.0-beta4

```
<span class="light exception">System.InvalidOperationException</span><br />
<span class="heavy">Incorrect Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8</span><br />
<div class="stacktrace">
<pre><span class="faded">at Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Core.</span>FormFeature.&lt;ReadFormAsync&gt;d__12.MoveNext<span class="faded">
;()</span></pre>
    <br /><pre><span class="faded">at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.</span>TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess<span class="faded">(Task task)</span></pre>
    <br /><pre><span class="faded">at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.</span>TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification<span class="faded">(Task task)</span></pre>
    <br /><pre><span class="faded">at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.</span>TaskAwaiter&lt;TResult&gt;.GetResult<span class="faded">()</span></pre>
    <br /><pre><span class="faded">at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.</span>AntiForgeryTokenStore.&lt;GetFormTokenAsync&gt;d__4.MoveNext<span class="faded">()</span></pre>
```

Comment: Issue is resolved. Refer to following link. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2579

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom validation attribute for this (works with beta4).
Use it just like the regular one.

```cs
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenFromHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IFilter {
    public override void OnActionExecuting (ActionExecutingContext actionContext) {
        if (actionContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        AntiForgery antiForgery = actionContext.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(AntiForgery)) as AntiForgery;

        var options = actionContext.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<MvcOptions>)) as IOptions<MvcOptions>;
        var config = options.Options.AntiForgeryOptions;

        var request = actionContext.HttpContext.Request;

        String cookieToken = request.Cookies[config.CookieName];
        String formToken   = request.Headers.Get("X-XSRF-Token");

        antiForgery.Validate(actionContext.HttpContext, cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

In angular, I set up `$http` in the app's `run` method as follows:

```js
$http.defaults
     .headers
     .common[$http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName] = angular.element("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']")
                                                     .attr("value");
```